# Inline::Java conflicts with Parallel::ForkManager

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, inline

I am having problem with calling both `Parallel::ForkManager` and `Inline::Java` at the same time. Specifically, if I call the `Inline::Java` with the `JNI => 1` option (which I have to), then the fork process doesn't come back to the parent. Here are the codes:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

##### Calling Inline::Java #####
use Inline Java => <<END, JNI => 1;

END
###### End of Inline::Java #####

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(2);
for my $i (0..1) {
    $pm->start and next;
    print "Inside process $i\n";
    $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
print "Back to Parent.\n";
```

If I run this program, it goes into the child processes but never comes back to the parent. If I remove the 3 lines between the comments, it runs fine. If I change the `JNI => 1` to `JNI => 0` (not that I'm allowed to change that parameter for my purpose), then there is an error message of `Lost connection with Java virtual machine at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Inline/Java.pm line 975`.

Does anyone have a clue how to resolve the conflict? I also have to call the Inline::Java before the parallel process so using `require` after parallel is done is not an option. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every child is talking over the same socket, which leads to the VM receiving jibberish.

You need to delay making a connection to the VM so that it's done in the children instead of it the parent.

You could move all thing Inline::Java-related into another module, then use `require Child;` (not `use Child;`) after `start`.

If you need to use Inline::Java before launching the child, do it in a different process.

Comment: Appreciate your analysis. Your solution, though, unfortunately is not suitable for me to implement as I noted at the end of the original question that the Inline::Java process has to be performed *prior to* forking. btw, the Inline::Java is already in a separate module. I just merged all scripts here for illustration purpose.

Comment: @Zhang18, Read again. My solution doesn't prevent you from using Inline::Java before the P::FM loop. You just have to do it in a separate process.

Comment: I see - you're absolutely right. Instead of going into each child process to call JVM, I managed to just go into one child, call JVM, return results to parent, and then fork into many children. So the key is to never run JVM in the parent. THx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Using forks with `Inline::Java` is going to be a problem. Your perl script needs to maintain a TCP connection with the JVM. When you fork a new process, the same file descriptors for communicating with the JVM are passed to the child process so the parent and all the child processes are using the same sockets. That won't work. You need to redesign your application.

One possibility (which you have already discounted) is to delay starting the JVM until after a fork, starting a new JVM in each child process.

Another approach is to forget about forking from Perl and to leverage Java's superior threading model to do parallelization. Design your Java code to perform its tasks in new threads, and start new threads from Perl:

```
my $java = ... entry point to JVM ...

for my $n (1 .. $num_threads) {
    $java->startNewThread(@inputs)
}
$java->waitForThreadsToFinish();
$result = $java->getResults();
```

Perl also has its own threading model (see [`threads`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads) and [`threads::shared`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads%3a%3ashared)). I doubt that Perl's threads will work for this problem, but it still might be worth a try.

---

Update: another possibility that is mentioned in the [`Inline::Java`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline%3a%3aJava#SHARED_JVM) docs is to use a shared JVM. Invoke `Inline::Java` with the option `SHARED_JVM => 1`, and when a new child process starts, call `Inline::Java::reconnect_JVM()` from the child to make a fresh connection. The downsides of this approach are

1. it keeps the JVM active after the program ends, so you have to remember to kill the JVM
2. it is incompatible with the option `JNI => 1`, which might be a dealbreaker to the OP.

Comment: Perl's threads won't help because you would still have the same problem of having multiple tasks trying to simultaneously use the same socket.

Comment: Just to be clear, the Java thread approach should work. My comment is on the remarks in mob's last paragraph only.