# Starting JVM for Inline

Tags: java, perl, jvm

I have a Perl script that uses `Inline::Java` and just *has* to `fork` (it is a server and I want it to handle multiple connections simultaneously).

So I wanted to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756780/2025742) which makes use of a shared JVM with `SHARED_JVM => 1`. Since the JVM is not shutdown when the script exits, I want to reuse it with `START_JVM => 0`. But since it might just be the first time I start the server, I would also like to have a `BEGIN` block make sure a JVM is running before calling `use Inline`.

My question is very simple, but I couldn't find any answer on the web: How do I simply start a JVM? I've looked at `man java` and there seems to be just no option that means "start and just listen for connections".

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do in Perl, if this helps:

```
BEGIN {
    &start_jvm unless &jvm_is_running;
}

use Inline (
    Java       => 'STUDY',
    SHARED_JVM => 1,
    START_JVM  => 0,
    STUDY      => ['JavaStuff'],
);

if (fork) {
    JavaStuff->do_something;
    wait;
}
else {
    Inline::Java::reconnect_JVM();
    JavaStuff->do_something;
}
```

What I need help with is writing the `start_jvm` subroutine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a working `jvm_is_running` function, just use it to determine whether Inline::Java should start the JVM.

```
use Inline (
    Java       => 'STUDY',
    SHARED_JVM => 1,
    START_JVM  => jvm_is_running() ? 0 : 1,
    STUDY      => ['JavaStuff'],
);
```

Comment: Ta, I'm feeling a bit stupid not having thought of that. Still, if you or someone do know how to write the `start_jvm` function, I'm curious to know how it should work.

Comment: The source code to Inline::Java::JVM shows how it's done. In particular look for where the variable `$cmd` is defined - this appears to be a command string. If you edit your version of the module to do a `print STDERR $cmd;` at that point, you should see the full command string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to details provided by [tobyink,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990570/tobyink) I am able to answer my own question, which was based on a the *erroneous* assumption that the JVM itself provides a server and a protocole.

As a matter of fact, one major component of `Inline::Java` is a server, written in Java, which handles request by the `Inline::Java::JVM` client, written in Perl.

Therefore, the command-line to launch the server is:

```
$ java org.perl.inline.java.InlineJavaServer <DEBUG> <HOST> <PORT> <SHARED_JVM> <PRIVATE> <NATIVE_DOUBLES>
```

where all parameters correspond to configuration options described in the [`Inline::Java` documentation.](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Java/Java.pod#CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS)

Therefore, in my case, the `start_jvm` subroutine would be:

```
sub start_jvm {
    system
      'java org.perl.inline.java.InlineJavaServer 0 localhost 7891 true false false';
}
```

(Not that it should be defined: tobyink's solution, while it did not directly address the question I asked, is much better.)

As for the `jvm_is_running` subroutine, this is how I defined it:

```
use Proc::ProcessTable;

use constant {
    JAVA          => 'java',
    INLINE_SERVER => 'org.perl.inline.java.InlineJavaServer',
};

sub jvm_is_running {
    my $pt = new Proc::ProcessTable;
    return grep {
        $_->fname eq JAVA && ( split /\s/, $_->cmndline )[1] eq INLINE_SERVER
    } @{ $pt->table };
}
```